# Using Int type vs. Integral constraint. Advantage?

Tags: haskell, int, typeclass

Consider these (more or less) equivalent type signatures:

```
f1 :: [a] -> Int -> a
f2 :: Integral b => [a] -> b -> a
```

*f2* is more general than *f1*, and that is a big advantage, but is there an advantage of *f1* over *f2*?

It seems that in the solutions to the H-99 problems, and in many posted solutions to various Project Euler problems, the *f1* form appears much more often than the *f2*.

I'm not sure why.  Is it simply programmer laziness, or is there a performance cost in going with the more general version (*f2*), or is there another reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Often this is due to people wanting to use the integral in conjunction with results from `length` and other functions already constrained to `Int`.  While there are often `generic`* functions such as `genericLength`, these names are longer and not in the Prelude.
- Performance of `Int` is more easily understood.  Performance for `Integral a` depends on a large part on if the function gets specialized for the particular instance of `Integral`.
- `Int` is often not just sufficient but also honest.  For example, strict `ByteString`s can't  be over an `Int` size (typically, please don't comment with esoteric examples) assuming your compiler uses machine word or larger `Int`s and not the darned standard [29+ bits](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch18.html#x26-22300018).
- Overuse of type classes muddies up the signatures, making the language less readable.  Were extreme generalization to become common, particularly for the primitive functions, I think we would need to find a more succinct way to express the constraints to keep from driving programmers mad.